# I want only all cities of "INDIA" to show through ngAutocomplete..??? which changes I have to make in ngAutocomplete..?

Tags: google-maps

I just want to give all cities of India in options through ngAutocomplete.js...well below code of ngAutocomplete.js

```
    var opts;
    var initOpts = function() {
      opts = {}
      if (scope.options) {
        if (scope.options.types) {
          opts.types = []
          opts.types.push(scope.options.types)
        }
        if (scope.options.bounds) {
          opts.bounds = scope.options.bounds
        }
        if (scope.options.country) {
          opts.componentRestrictions = {
            country: 'IN'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: check out this demo  http://plnkr.co/edit/GE34ojss9xMGm0024FvM?p=preview  by changing country 'ca' to  'in'  it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $scope.getOnlyINDIA = {
                      country: 'in', 
                      types: '(cities)'
                       };
```

add this into controller then on auto-complete textbox add...

```
           options="getOnlyINDIA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately for you, there is [Autocomplete: Restrict the search to a specific country](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area) from the Google JS docs. This functionality uses the `componentRestrictions` option to restrict the autocomplete search to a particular country. Here's a snippet for you:

```
 var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Here's a [full working demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch) from the Google Maps sample.